# Using a DMF5001NY-LY LCD with a Raspberry Pi Pico W

Tags: lcd, adapter, raspberry-pi-pico

I just got myself a Raspberry Pi Pico to learn electronics and MicroPython. I was digging in my pile of "I bought this to do something one day with it, but never did" and found an old [DMF5001NY-L](https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/167102/OPTREX/DMF5001NYL/3144/14/DMF5001NYL.html) from Optrex. It has a 20-pin connector connected to a Toshiba T6963C driver with an 8-bit data bus. I was hoping to use it for a project on my Pico or at least see if it is still in working condition.

New to Pico so I need some help here. I know I can use a 16x2 LCD via a serial bus using the I2C backpack adapter. I was hoping that something like that exists for this type of LCD screen.

Comment: But you have a 16x2 LCD, so why are you asking if there are I2C backpacks for your LCD like there is for 16x2 LCDs?

Comment: I am asking if something like the I2C backpack for 16x2 exist for this big LCD. But I do know that it does exist for 16x2 LCD. And I really would like to use the big 5.1" LCD.

Comment: Wait, so you gave a link to a datasheet of a display you don't have, instead of giving a link to a display you do have? What's the point in that? Also you can use GPIO for the display, you just need more pins.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted in the wrong link. XD